# Does having 2-factor authentication help with HeartBleed?

Tags: tls, authentication, openssl, multi-factor, heartbleed

I was talking with a friend about HeartBleed, and he mentioned that he had 2-factor authentication enabled on all the sites that supported it, so even with his username and passwords, nobody would be able to login without his phone too.

I told him to change his passwords anyway.

But I'm interested to know; was he right about 2-factor authentication protecting him from the worst of it?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: If he had recently logged in, the 2FA secret could still be present in the server's memory when an attack occurred, allowing an attacker to generate his own tokens.

Comment: It probably wouldn't help too much.

Comment: Somewhat on a tangent, what Facebook and Google does with strange logins is interesting too. If you log on from a different country or far away, it locks down the account if you have something like a secondary email or phone number to verify.

Comment: In many 2FA implementations, the token is tied to the browser that you are logging in from.

On Facebook and Google for example, I need to establish a 2FA token for each computer that I log in from. The token is only good one time. I can't even use the token in two different browsers on the same computer. This would mean that 2FA would protect against Heartbleed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski you're not wrong! 2FA *does* protect against heartbleed on the condition that the process that generates the OTPs is not running openssl and using TLS in some way that makes it exploitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree with Mark. A main goal of SSL/TLS is the protection of the long term key (i.e. the private certificate). If an attacker can obtain the key, the implementation must be considered broken.

It does not matter if you use two-factor authentication or not. If I know the server's secret key, I can decrypt your traffic either directly (without PFS) or via MITM (with PFS). I can steal your session cookies or whatever and do everything without your token. I can even steal your TCP sessions.

Comment: We were talking in the concept of grabbing account info and using it to log in...If I'm understanding this correctly, two-factor authentication would protect from someone logging in as you. Right?

Comment: It depends on how the second-factor is calculated. I assume that this is most often not exploitable. However, if the secret from which a token is calculated resides within the 65k the attacker can read, the token is compromised.

Comment: @fr00tyl00p it's 64k, and also there is no reason for the code generating the OTP to be in the same process as openssl.

Comment: It's 16k actually.

Comment: Main vulnerability is that the attacker can sniff out the shared secret between the client and server used for generating one-time passwords. If its loaded into RAM on the server, Heartbleed can leak the shared OTP secret, rendering 2FA ineffective.

Answer (score 5):

Proper two-factor authentication (authentication with both a password and a single-use token sent via an external channel) provides protection against the Heartbleed attack.  An attacker can get both the password and the token, but with a proper implementation, the token is worthless for actually attempting a login of their own: it's single-use, and it doesn't give any clue as to what the next token will be.

The "wish-it-was-two-factor" authentication used by entirely too many sites (username, password, trivia question about you) provides absolutely no protection.

Comment: Are well-known implementations truly single-use? In other words, could a fast (scripted) login use the current token before it expires?

Comment: I don't know about SecurID and other time-based systems, but demand-based systems such as sending a token via SMS should invalidate the token the first time it's used.

Comment: If the two-factor token generator's seed was exposed by Heartbleed then two-factor is entirely worthless.  If you're using two-factor, whatever app you are using you should generate a new seed immediately if you haven't done so since the public disclosure of Heartbleed.